# find recurrence equation of an algorithm java

Tags: java, algorithm, recurrence

I really don't know how to find the recurrence equation of an algorithm
I've read the other questions about this subject but there are some stuff that I still don't get.
for example in the following code (actually the pseudo-code :) ):

```
MergeSort(list "L" of "n" elements):
if n=<1 then return L
L1 <- MergeSort(L1... n/2)
L2 <- MergeSort(L(n/2 +1) ... n)
L <- Merge(L1, L2) 
return L
```

the recurrence equation is the following:
T(1) = b
T(n) = c1 + c2.n + 2T(n/2)

I don't get what is c1, c2 and b 
thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Merge sort on n elements:**

1. If n = 1 , return the solitary element.
2. Else , Recursively sort [1...n/2] elements and [n/2+1...n] elements.
3. Merge the 2 sorted arrays.

Let the total time taken to merge-sort an array of *n* elements be *T(n)*.
As we know the base case is if the number of elements *n* is *1* , then we don't need to apply merge sort algorithm , we can just return that element .

```
if n=<1 then return L
```

This will take a constant time , say *c1*.

If elements are greater than *1* then split the array from *[1..n/2]* and *[n/2+1...n]* and recursively merge-sort them.

```
L1 <- MergeSort(L1... n/2)
L2 <- MergeSort(L(n/2 +1) ... n)
```

So, as we assumed the time taken to merge-sort *n* elements is *T(n)* , then the time taken to sort each of the sub-array containing approximately *n/2* elements will be *T(n/2)*.

We need to merge the sub-arrays after sorting , time taken to merge *n* elements will be linear function of the *n* i.e. *c2.n* where *c2* is the constant time taken to place an element in its specific position in the final sorted array.